# How to save a text file without format string in C

Tags: string, file, format

I want to save text into a file with this function that:

```
 void wl (char* buff[],char lp[],char mt[])
 {
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen(lp, mt);

  fprintf(fp, buff);
  fclose (fp);
  }
```

If I run it via a simple input buffer like "abcd" .... "abcd" will save into the destination file.

However, if I include text that contains "%s %d ...." or other C format strings ... it will save the wrong data.

I would like to know how I can save a string like "ab%cd" into a file. I know that if I replace % with %%, it will save correctly but I can't write the correct replace code for `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `fprintf(fp, "%s", buff)` or use `fputs(buff, fp)` that does the same.

You should probably never use any input as a formatting string - this can lead to exploits.

Comment: TanQ for your answer and your security tip  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [fputs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputs/) and [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) - neither of them perform any substitution.  The former is probably all you're looking for, and easier to use as well, but fwrite gives you a little more power if you need it (it's typically used to write arbitrary binary to a file).

Hope that helps!

**PS:**  Or, for a really lame, hackish solution, try:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", buff); //Yuck!
```